# How to combine two .rda files in R?

Tags: r, rda

I have two .rda files with many variables and dataframes already set to some values. Both the rda files have same variable names and dataframe names. However, their order is different. I want to combine two rda files into 1 single .rda file like the way we append two dataframes.

I tried to use `rbind` to combine two objects containing .rda files like below

```
X <- c(1,2,3)
Y <- c("A","B","C")

rbind(X,Y)

save(X,Y,file="samplerda.rda")
load(file = "samplerda.rda")


X <- c(4,5,6)
Y <- c("D","E","F")
save(X,Y,file="samplerda1.rda")
load(file = "samplerda1.rda")

ob1 <- load(file = "samplerda.rda")
ob2 <- load(file = "samplerda1.rda")
combine12 <- rbind(ob1, ob2)
save(combine12, file="En1.rda")
load("En1.rda")
print(combine12)
```

However I print combine12 object i was expecting below output

```
X  Y 
1 "A"
2 "B"
3 "C"
4 "D"
5 "E"
6 "F"
```

Actual Output is

```
    [,1] [,2]
ob1 "X"  "Y" 
ob2 "X"  "Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `load()` function returns the names of the objects it loaded, so both `ob1` and `ob2` will contain `c("X", "Y")` and when you `rbind` them, you get the matrix you saw in `combine12`.

You'll need much more complicated code to do what you want, for example:

```
env1 <- new.env()
env2 <- new.env()
ob1 <- load(file = "samplerda.rda", envir = env1)
ob2 <- load(file = "samplerda1.rda", envir = env2)
stopifnot(all(ob1 == ob2))  # Sanity check

combine12 <- list()
for (n in ob1) {
  combine12[[n]] <- c(get(n, env1), get(n, env2))
}
combine12 <- as.data.frame(combine12)
```